# Cannot read error formControl

Tags: validation, passwords, angular2-forms

I had created a method to validate password and cofirmpassword in angular 2. I create a file password-validation.ts

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
export class PasswordValidation {
static MatchPassword(_ac: AbstractControl) {
   let password = _ac.get('password').value;
   let confirmPassword = _ac.get('password_confirm').value;
    if(password != confirmPassword) {
        console.log('false');
        _ac.get('password_confirm').setErrors( {"MatchPassword": true} 
)
    } else {
        console.log('true');
        return null
    }
}
}
```

In register.ts

```
  this.registerForm = this._fb.group({
  firstname: [''],
  lastname: [''],
  email: [''],
  password: [''],
  password_confirm: []
},
  {
    validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword
  });
```

And in html

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" required=" " formControlName="password">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password Confirmation" required=" " formControlName="password_confirm">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.password_confirm.error?.MatchPassword">Password not match</div>
```

However I cannot show the alert. Maybe registerForm.controls.password_confirm.error?.MatchPassword don't handle.

What should I do in this case? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword.bind(this)
```

Does it help?